# Multiplying 2 (small) numbers gives negatives solution, not overflow...so why?

Tags: java, math, int

I searched and found topics relating to this issue but in all of them here the reason was overflow (the result was too big for an int type,right?).
but in this case the result is less than the max value for int and still produces a negative number from 2 positives. and I wonder why.

heres the code:

```
int s = (50*49*48*47*46*45);
out.println(s);

OUTPUT:
-1443597888
```

now when i try 449 instead of 49:

```
int s = (50*449*48*47*46*45);
out.println(s);

OUTPUT:
1760488896
```

so why does that happen?
I generally want to calculate (50*49*48*47*46*45)/(1*2*3*4*5*6) but it keeps giving negative result.

Thanks for the help.

Oh Yeah I am using Java, a very early beginner so I have little clue of whats going on. thanks.

Comment: Please add the relevant language tag.

Comment: What do you believe the max value for int to be?

Comment: *I generally want to calculate (50*49*48*47*46*45)/(1*2*3*4*5*6)* so, generally, eliminate common factors in numerator and denominator just as you would if you were computing that expression by hand.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark, Eliminating common factors is not trivial to implement. It's probably better to just switch to a larger data type here.

Comment: using java, thought it was a site just for Java.  the max value for int is 2147483647 which is bigger than the result for the above mentioned expression.

Comment: @RYU: You might want to use the [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) class for your calculations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "int" type of your programming language of choice probably uses 32-bit signed integer representation. That means that a fixed number of bits is used to represent a number, so the range of numbers that can be stored is limited. Most usually, the range is -2147483648 to 2147483647 (or written differently, -2^31 to 2^31-1), best consult documentation for your programming language for confirmation.

So, an int can only be in that limited range, but the actual result of your calculation (50*49*48*47*46*45) would be 11441304000, which is well outside that range, so one of the multiplications causes an overflow.

Different programming languages and platforms handle that in different ways, but one usual result is that the number simply wraps around, so that 2147483647+1 will result in -2147483648. Other programming languages will catch this and generate an error. Others again will automatically switch to a larger representation, so you don't get an overflow at all but can work with arbitrarily large numbers.

The language you are using appears to belong to the first group which silently overflows, so you will simply get a wrong result.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specified the language which you use, neither the number of bits for int representation. But is seems that it IS an overflow problem.

From your second example:

`50*449*48*47*46*45` is `104839704000` which is binary:
`01100001101000111011101110110111000000`

but the result which you get is `1760488896` which is binary:
`00000001101000111011101110110111000000`

First bits (the `0110...` at the beginning) were cut off.

Seems that you have 32bit for int representation. Which is to small to represent `11441304000` - the result of `50*49*48*47*46*45`.

You get wrong result in both cases. Why it's negative only at first example?

The binary representation of `11441304000` is

010 **10101001111101000111000111000000**

But only 32 (bolded) bits fits into your integer variable. The first of them is `1`, which is translated to negative decimal value.

Comment: I am a beginner using Java so I have no clue about bits right now..how can i know early on when an expression is going to give negative result when its not mathematically correct? (only "binarically")  thanks.

Comment: An integer has it's maximum value. If you try to assing to it somethin bigger you will get some wrong, possibly negative value. I think your problem is not a negative value, but just WRONG value. I'm not sure if you noticed that in your 2nd example (with `449`) the result is also wrong. Answering your question: To detect an overflow you could try something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657834/how-can-i-check-if-multiplying-two-numbers-in-java-will-cause-an-overflow

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, the problem is that computing `50*49*48 ...` is too big to fit in a Java `int`. You could switch to a bigger fixed-precision type, namely `long`, but then you'll run into the problem for some other, larger, arguments. My advice is to use Java's `BigInteger` type to store the result.