# Given two arrays, how can I tell if a math result would overflow?

Tags: c#

In this case, `sum` is an int and I am intentionally setting `one[]` and `[two]` to `int.MaxValue`.

The result for `sum` is 1.

How can I tell if the result of a math function is going to overflow here, *prior* to attempting it?

```
sum += one[i] * two[i];
```

Comment: Simply: you can´t.

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657834/how-can-i-check-if-multiplying-two-numbers-in-java-will-cause-an-overflow

Comment: What if your maths get more complicated, e.g. `Math.Pow(1231221, 2322)`? It´s impossible to know *before* you execute it and see what happens.

Comment: @HimBromBeere that is true for any function you call. but I think, question is about basic ops CPU can handle.

Comment: I did this using the C# `checked()` keyword, which forces it to throw.  It's the only way I can catch it and handle it.  I don't see any way around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By 'overflow', did you mean it will exceed `int.MaxValue`?
If so, try to use [`checked` block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/checked).
As [@AlexD](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3246555/alexd) mentioned in comments, it won't perform a prior-check; however, it will raise an exception in case of overflow.

Quote and code sample are taken from MSDN:

> The checked keyword is used to explicitly enable overflow checking for integral-type arithmetic operations and conversions.

```
// If the previous sum is attempted in a checked environment, an 
// OverflowException error is raised.

// Checked expression.
Console.WriteLine(checked(2147483647 + ten));

// Checked block.
checked
{
    int i3 = 2147483647 + ten;
    Console.WriteLine(i3);
}
```